# How to extract ONLY lat, lon values for node "osm_type":"node" in a Nominatim response using Google Refine

Tags: openrefine, nominatim

I'm using Google Refine to geocoding addresses with requests to Nominatim API as suggested in this great post https://opensas.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/using-openrefine-to-geocode-your-data-using-google-and-openstreetmap-api/.

All works fine: here you are two samples ...

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&q=Via%20Pietro%20Paleocapa%2073,Alzano%20Lombardo,Italia
```

produces

```
[{"place_id":"55017260","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"22565087","boundingbox":["45.7324335","45.736092","9.7222512","9.7235157"],"lat":"45.7343899","lon":"9.7231855","display_name":"Via Pietro Paleocapa, Alzano Lombardo, BG, Lombardy, 24027, Italy","class":"highway","type":"unclassified","importance":0.6}]
```

and

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&q=Via%20Cernaia%2020,%20Torino%20,%20Italia
```

produces

```
[{"place_id":"24085209","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"2334729647","boundingbox":["45.0715728","45.0715728","7.6742348","7.6742348"],"lat":"45.0715728","lon":"7.6742348","display_name":"20, Via Cernaia, Quadrilatero Romano, Circoscrizione 1, Turin, TO, Piemont, 10122, Italy","class":"place","type":"house","importance":0.201}]
```

The differences are about that the first response has a "osm_type":"way" type and the second one has a "osm_type":"node" type.

I'm interested ONLY in responses about "osm_type":"node", and for these ones I'd like to extract lat and lon values.

I don't know how to extract them using GREL in Google Refine ..... Any suggestions?

If could be useful I can also obtain the reponses in XML ... here you're the requests

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&q=Via%20Pietro%20Paleocapa%2073,Alzano%20Lombardo,Italia&format=xml

http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&q=Via%20Cernaia%2020,%20Torino%20,%20Italia&format=xml
```

Comment: As the blog post you found mentions, OpenRefine is the current name for what used to be called Google Refine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this in several ways, but the basic step is to extract the osm_type. Given the JSON you've posted here the GREL would be:

```
value.parseJson()[0].osm_type
```

One approach would be to create a column based on this value, then use a Facet to filter to those where the value in this new column is 'node'.

Alternatively you could combine the steps in a single GREL statement using 'if':

```
if(value.parseJson()[0].osm_type=="node",value.parseJson()[0].lat,"")
```

This extracts the latitude if osm_type is equal to 'node' and otherwise puts an empty string in the cell.

Comment: Owen, you "if" solution what It is exactly what I was looking for. I'll try also, for  my knownledge, the "facet" solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak on Owen's formula can remove some of the redundancy:

```
with(value.parseJson()[0], place, if(place.osm_type=='node',place.lat,''))
```

It's not a big savings here, but it's a good technique to know about when the expressions get longer and more complex.  The `with` control function assigns a value to a variable that you can use later.

Comment: Thank Tom! Where can I find documentation about this advanced stuff?

Comment: They're all included in the Help tab for the expression preview dialog, but it's just a long list without much categorization.  A more approachable source is the [wiki](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Documentation-For-Users) which includes both a set of [recipes/examples](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Documentation-For-Users#recipes-and-worked-examples) and a [language reference](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/General-Refine-Expression-Language)